# How to check if table variable have id or not

Tags: sql-server, join, merge, cross-join

I have the following table variable

```
DECLARE @insertedTable Table (ServiceId INT)
```

I insert ServiceId to it from some SQL query,

Now I need to insert values to `BranchServices` table with cross join `@insertedTable`

I wrote following SQL query

```
INSERT INTO BranchServices
    SELECT b.BranchId
    ,its.ServiceId
    ,CASE WHEN(SELECT MIN(SortValue) FROM BranchServices WHERE FkBranchId = b.BranchId) IS NOT NULL THEN 0 END
     FROM @insertedTable its
    CROSS JOIN Branch b where b.IsActive = 1;
```

The above query works fine when the `@insertedTable` table does not exist `ServiceId` same as the `BranchServices` table. Because `BranchServices`'s table `ServiceId` are primary keys.

So now I need to check, If `BranchServices` table already has `ServiceId` I don't need to run the following query, otherwise, I need to run a query. How can I do it using a merge? If yes how to write it

```
INSERT INTO BranchServices
    SELECT b.BranchId
    ,its.ServiceId
    ,CASE WHEN(SELECT MIN(SortValue) FROM BranchServices WHERE FkBranchId = b.BranchId) IS NOT NULL THEN 0 END
     FROM @insertedTable its
    CROSS JOIN Branch b where b.IsActive = 1;
```

Comment: Perform a `LEFT JOIN` to `BranchServices` and check that the value of `ServiceId` (in `BranchServices`) is `NULL`?

Comment: @Larnu can you please give me a full answer

Comment: @Larnu no, its not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a total guess:

```
INSERT INTO BranchServices (BranchId, ServiceId, OtherColumn) --Don't know what the name of the third column is
SELECT b.BranchId,
       its.ServiceId,
       CASE WHEN (SELECT MIN(SortValue)FROM BranchServices WHERE FkBranchId = b.BranchId) IS NOT NULL THEN 0 END
FROM @insertedTable its
     CROSS JOIN Branch b
     LEFT JOIN BranchServices BS ON its.ServiceId = BS.ServiceId
WHERE b.IsActive = 1
  AND BS.ServiceId IS NULL;
```

*Side note, white space is really important for writing readable code, and i suggest making **good** use of it.*

Comment: why check `AND BS.FkServiceId IS NULL;` ?

Comment: And sir one more thing, you mean I need to write SQL code with white space? I'm I right

Comment: *"why check AND BS.FkServiceId IS NULL;"* Because that's what you asked for, @Adam: *"So now I need to check, If `BranchServices` table already have `ServiceId` I don't need to run the following query, otherwise, need to run a query."*.

Comment: *"you mean I need to write SQL code with white space?"* Yes, your SQL is all Left Aligned, making it harder to read.